# Error : " Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' "

Tags: typescript, vue.js, query-string

I'm working on a Vue project also using TypeScript and axios for API calls while working on a Reset Password component my resetPassword function in the auth.ts file looks like this

```
resetPassword(password1: string, password2: string, uid: string, token: string): Promise<any> {
      
      return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        axios
            .post("API", { password1, password2, uid, token })
            .then((res : any) => {
              resolve(//RESOLVE);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              //REJECT
            })
      })
    }
```

In my ResetPassword.vue file I'm using the newPassword as shown below

```
this.resetPassword(password1.value, password2.value, this.$route.params.id, this.$route.params.resetID).then(
      (res) => {
        if(password1.value == password2.value){
            Notification{
                "SUCCESS"
            });
          }
```

In my ResetPassword.vue file the 3rd param im getting an error saying **"Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'."**

I'm a little new to ts and i needed a little help with it.

I'm confused between 2 solution here should i do **this.$route.params.id as string** *or is it better to do* **this.$route.params.id.toString()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route params could contain many values with the same key. That is why it could be an array of strings rather than a single string. If you are sure, that there is only one param you can use `as string` to basically tell the typescript compiler that you know that this variable is 100% a `string` and not `string[]`

```
this.resetPassword(password1.value, password2.value, this.$route.params.id as string, this.$route.params.resetID as string)
```

If you will use `.toString()` and there will be an array like `["foo", "bar"]`, you would get `"foo,bar"` as the result of `.toString()`

If you are unsure whether it is an array or not, you could check it, and if it is an array then take the first value:

```
let id: string;
if (Array.isArray(this.$route.params.id)) {
    id = this.$route.params.id[0];
} else {
    id = this.$route.params.id;
}
```

Comment: Okay yes that makes a lot of sense. Thank You!!